# What's the best way of making conditions in React.Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Lately, I have been following a tutorial on react js and I see that the mentor write his if conditions everywhere, and when I do like him exactly the interpreter throws an error especially in functional components I am gonna show the mentors code which shows me an error then how I fixed it.

```
import {React , useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const Validation = (props) =>{

let [msg,changemsg] = useState('');

    if(props.text.length === 0){
        changemsg('');
    }else if(props.text.length < 5){
        changemsg('too short');
    }else{
        changemsg('good');
    }

return (
   <div>
    <h1>{msg}</h1>
   </div>
  );
}

export default Validation;
```

And here's how i fixed it

```
import {React , useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const Validation = (props) =>{

let [msg,changemsg] = useState('');

useEffect(()=>{
    if(props.text.length === 0){
        changemsg('');
    }else if(props.text.length < 5){
        changemsg('too short');
    }else{
        changemsg('good');
    }
})


return (
   <div>
    <h1>{msg}</h1>
   </div>
  );
}
```

the thing that concerns me here while using the useEffect() hook is the performance of the application. does using hooks make app performance weak ? and what's the best approach to write things like the if loop inside both functional and class components.

Thank you.

Comment: What error does the first code snippet throw?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the first version, and your "fix" is at best unnecessary. What error are you getting?

Comment: The error is " Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop"

Comment: If you fail to pass in a text prop your component will render in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show something, depending on props, you don't need useState.
Better to use hook [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

```
const msg = useMemo(()=>{
    if(props.text.length === 0){
        return '';
    }else if(props.text.length < 5){
        return 'too short';
    }else{
        return 'good';
    }
}, [props.text])
```

Hook useMemo allows preparing some value. The value will be updated only if dependencies (in your case it's props.text) will be updated.